# How can I commit in GitLab to link it to the bug id in Mantis BT?

Tags: gitlab, mantis

I have committed the code in GitLab but i want that commit to be linked with a bug id in Mantis BT. Can someone help in telling how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that but it's possible to add a *Custom Issue Tracker* to GitLab. Go to the `Admin Area` -> `Service Templates` -> `Custom Issue Tracker`. Here you have to configure the URL of your Mantis. Then GitLab should link Commit messages like "Fixes #123" to your Mantis.

Comment: This does not work for Mantis. "Custom Issue Tracker" in Gitlab assumes that bugs IDs look like "ANYTHING-ID", especially because "ANYTHING is a placeholder to differentiate against GitLab issues, which are referenced with #<ID>" (source: [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/custom_issue_tracker.html))

Answer (score 0):

As for the moment of writing (July 2019) there were no clean way to do this.

The only more or less suitable option is "Custom issue tracker" in Gitlab (`Settings` -> `Integrations` -> `Custom Issue Tracker`), however it requires you to have issue prefix i.e. "MYPROJ-123" in commit message.

So if you're fine with writing dummy prefix "PROJ-132" then it will work.